How to reference c# .netstandard(2.0)(uses third party dependencies like OnnxRuntime,Opencvsharp) class library in WPF(.net framework 4.7.2) UI app?

Hi i have created a class library in c# visual studio in .net standard 2.0. a. It has onnxruntime ,opencvsharp etc dependencies.

Now i am building this library and using it in my WPF UI application. But i am getting following error.


The given version [14] is not supported, only version 1 to 10 is supported in this build. Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.dll Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have tried to reference the library directory from the bin folder in the WPF UI App. But it is not solving problem. The bin folder of library don't has onnxruntime.dll .
The issue is not resolving with this approach also.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
